# In Swift, a generic function that returns a function of the same type gives me "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function"

Tags: swift, generics

This function takes a `Void -> T` function and returns a `Void -> T` function.

```
func future<T>(f: Void -> T) -> Void -> T {
    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.lockQueue", nil)
    var results: T?

    dispatch_async(queue) {
        results = f()
    }

    return {
        dispatch_sync(queue) {}
        return results!
    }
}
```

If I use it like this:

```
let f = future<Int> {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 10
}
```

I get the error "Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function".

If I however set the explicit type to `Void -> Int` like so:

```
let f: Void -> Int = future {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 10
}
```

It works but it doesn't look that good.
Can I change the function so that the I can use it in the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the function as a local function and pass it.

```
func sleepAndReturn() -> Int { 
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 10
}

let f = future(sleepAndReturn)
```

Alternatively you could use the `in` syntax to specify the type.

```
let f = future({ () -> Int in  
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 10
})
```

Or shorter:

```
let f = future({ _ -> Int in  
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 10
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should just work like this:

```
let f = future {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 10
}
```

... or if that is too difficult for Swift to figure out, then you can specify the closure parameters like this:

```
let f = future { Void -> Int in
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 10
}
```

Comment: Similar code does run on my x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu target.  Will check on XCode later then.  At any rate, the problem is that one does not explicitly specializes a generic.  Swift should be able to infer a particular type for gereric's parameter from the context.

Comment: Reading up on it, I understand now what the compiler means with not being able to specialize a generic function. The second example @AntonBronnikov is the one I think I'll go with.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the function in a struct and use it like this:

```
struct Future<T> {
    static func create(f: Void -> T) -> Void -> T {
        let queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.lockQueue", nil)
        var results: T?

        dispatch_async(queue) {
            results = f()
        }

        return {
            dispatch_sync(queue) {}
            return results!
        }
    }
}

let f = Future<Int>.create {
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2)
    return 20
}
```